# Import an HTML file from inside a Twig template

Tags: php, html, templates, symfony, twig

I want to import an HTML file from inside a Twig template. The HTML file is located at `/var/files/5` (with no extension). And I render the template like this:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../var/files/5';
$content = $this->get('templating')->render('ProConvocationBundle:Default:definitive-view.html.twig', array('path' => $path));
```

Inside the Twig template I import the HTML file like this:

```
{% include path %}
```

but it is not finding the path: *Unable to find template "/myDocumentRoot/../app/var/files/5"*

I've also tried several relative paths without success. Any idea of how to achieve it?

Comment: Is `/var/files/5` and absolute path or a path relative to your document root? It's a bit unclear since you're building the path with the document root, but `/var/...` could very well be an absolute path as well.

Comment: @thormeier - This is the absolute path of the document root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What causes this exception?

After digging in the Twig code a little, the following seems to cause this exception:

Twig tries to load the file from a known path/namespace, being bundle names (like `/var/www/myApplication/src/AcmeBundle/Resources/views`) and the `app` path being `myApplication/app/Resources/views`). Anyway it doesn't accept absolute paths, since it always tries to add a known path to the beginning of the given file.

```
<?php
// Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php

class Twig_Loader_Filesystem {

// ...
protected function findTemplate()
{
    // ...
    foreach ($this->paths[$namespace] as $path) {
        if (is_file($path.'/'.$shortname)) {
            return $this->cache[$name] = $path.'/'.$shortname;
        }
    }

    throw new Twig_Error_Loader(sprintf('Unable to find template "%s" (looked into: %s).', $name, implode(', ', $this->paths[$namespace])));
}
```

So it basically isn't possible to include a file by an absolue path, like in your example.

## How to solve this?

You've got a bunch of possibilities to achieve this behaviour:

### Add the path to the template loader

See post by @Adam Elsodaney

### Move the file

You could simply move your file from `app/var/files` to `app/Resources/views/var/files` and use the path `var/files/5` to include the file. This is probably not a suitable solution, since you want to keep those files in place.

### Write a Twig Extension

You could write your own extension that provides a function named something like `include_absolute()` that simply returns `file_get_contents($yourPath)`.

More on Twig extensions: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Be aware that you would might need to add the `|raw` filter to the output of the Twig function since a lot of stuff gets escaped everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I finally achieved it passing the raw content to the Twig template instead of try to read it from inside the template. But your options are also good.

Answer (score 1):

In Symfony, you should make everything relative to the Kernel root directory which is the `app` directory.

```
$uploadedTemplatesDir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../var/files';
```

Then add this to your templating loader

```
$this->get('twig.loader')->addPath($uploadedTemplatesDir);
```