# Twig absolute path variable in include

Tags: symfony, include, twig

my script defines a absolute path in PHP and gives it to the twig template with the `render()`-function. All works well, I can access my variables with `{{ varName }}` in the view. But if I try to use a absolute path as a variable inside a include-command like `{% include varName %}` it will say: Unable to find template. This will even happen if the absolute path is correct.

What am I missing here?

Comment: you need to pass this syntax i guess : YourBundle:View-Folder:view.html.twig

Comment: The problem is the include-file is not within the view-folder. My file is within the `Bundle\Somedir\somefile.html.twig`. Is there a way to handle it with this path?

Comment: The following question handles something related, perhaps the approaches in the answers lead you to a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435964/import-an-html-file-from-inside-a-twig-template/22438663

Answer (score 0):

Well it's weird but unfortunately I had no possibility to include a file from somewhere else not in the specific symfony structure. So I had to move all contents to the view folder.

I hope someone fixes this, which is anything but flexible.

Comment: This is possible, at least it is now with the current version of Twig. See my response below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38447656/3424147

Answer (score 0):

To add template search paths to `Twig_Loader_Filesystem`, you can use

```
$loader->addPath($templateDir);
```

or

```
$loader->prependPath($templateDir);
```

Where `$templateDir` is a parent directory and `$loader` is the variable containing your `Twig_Loader_Filesystem` object. In your example, you would want `$templateDir` to be the path where the Bundle directory is located.

Then, in your include do something like this:

```
{% include 'Bundle\Somedir\somefile.html.twig' %}
```

Twig will then search all paths in looking for `Bundle\Somedir\somefile.html.twig` and will return the first one it finds.

The Twig documentation on this subject can be found here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#twig-loader-filesystem

**Note:** Choice of using `addPath` or `prependPath` depends on which order you'd like Twig to search the directories in. Paths added using `prependPath` will be searched before any of the previously loaded paths.

**Caution:** The search order applies to *all* templates so if the path/filename you use in the `include` statement is not unique, you could end up overriding another template.